# How to create a branch with two parents

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have two dev branches, `dev_common` and `dev_huawei`(variant for special device). There are only few differences between them, so I need a master branch which parents are these two dev branches to commit public features.

For example, I create `feature` branch from `master` branch and do some public changes. Then, I can start pull request A(`feature` into `dev_common`) and pull request B(`feature` into `dev_huawei`) at the same time. My purpose is to avoid creating `feature_common` and `feature_huawei` with the same changes.

I've only used git before in a very basic form. Is my "For example" feasible? What is this operation called? Rebase or something else? Can I have my `master` with two parents in GUI(Sourcetree and Github)?

Thanks.

1. `dev_common`:

line1 for common device

line2 some public features

2. `dev_huawei`:

line1 for huawei device

line2 some public features

3. I start a new branch `feature` from `master`, and commit my change:

+line3 a new public feature

4. Merge `feature` into `dev_common`(commit1). Now `dev_common` is

line1 for common device

line2 some public features

line3 a new public feature

5. Merge `feature` into `dev_huawei`(commit2). Now `dev_huawei` is

line1 for huawei device // Here it does not mess up what should be kept

line2 some public features

line3 a new public feature

6. Merge `dev_common` into `master`, and I can begin from `master` again when add next feature.

Comment: A branch with more than one parent is a branch that points to a merge

Comment: *Branches* (or more precisely, branch *names*) in Git have no parent/child relationships at all. Only *commits* have parents; a commit with two or more parents is a merge commit.

Comment: Create your `feature` branch from the common ancestor of the two dev branches.

Comment: a branch is just a reference to a commit, so if you want a branch that have two parents, it means you want a commit that have two parents, a commit that have two parents is a merge

Comment: Yes you are right. I understand. It is a merge commit. I added some sequence of operations.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question : you need the **master** branch to have both content from the **dev_common** branch and **dev_huawei** branch

in this case, you can do the following :

go to a one of the branches : let's go to **dev_common** branch (if you have uncommitted files in the current branch, make sure to commit them before you switch to other branch)

```
git switch dev_common
```

then merge the content from **dev_huawei** to the current branch by : (this can give some merge conflicts, so fix them and continue

```
git merge dev_huawei
```

and then go to the **master** branch and run

```
git merge dev_common
```

This can give other conflicts, but if the **master** branch is the starting point without any commit that they are not in the other branchs, Git will do a **fast-forward**, and you'll not have any merge conflict.

Comment: "If I understand your question : you need the master branch to have both content from the dev_common branch and dev_huawei branch." No, it's the opposite. The master branch should contain no dev-specific content. That way, it can be merged into both dev_common and dev_huawei. The answer is to create the master branch from the common ancestor of the two dev branches. Then you can merge it into both dev branches without polluting each dev branch with content from the other dev branch.

Comment: In fact, in my repo, we had the ```master``` long time ago but I don' t know how it was create. After I merged a new feature into the two dev(commit1 and commit2), I merge ```dev_common``` into ```master```, and this commit' s parent is commit1 and commit2. Can your answer make such a ```master```?

Comment: @Raymond Chen Do you mean ```master``` is the main one, and only accepts ```dev_common```' s merge request because ```dev_huawei``` has a commit of line1?

Comment: Your problem description is somewhat confusing because you are using the term `master` in a way different from how most people use it. So let's not say `master` at all. You just want to be able to create a `feature` branch that can be merged into both `dev_huawei` and into `dev_common`. The way to do that is to make the feature branch based on the common ancestor of the two `dev_*` branches.

Comment: @Raymond Chen oh I get it. "the common ancestor of the two dev_* branches" is what I need. Thank you!